# Is it possible to insert an AsyncTask in its natural queue?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

My wording might be a little hard to understand, what i want to achieve is to create an indirect asynctask queue.

I have a method which creates an asynctask (named `Hide`) and executes it on the SERIAL_EXECUTOR. Now this method can be called several times ofc and then `Hide` asynctasks will be queued and executed one after another. But inside `Hide`'s doInBackground I would like to start another asynctask (also with SERIAL_EXECUTOR) called `Show` based on the stuff that happened before in `Hide`'s doInBackground, and I want this `Show` to be executed right after its caller `Hide`.

So if 3 threads call the main method and queues up 3 instances of `Hide` to be executed, then I would like my actual asynctask queue to look like this:

`Hide1`,`Hide2`,`Hide3`

`Hide1`,**`Show1`**, `Hide2`,`Hide3`

`Hide1`,**`Show1`**, `Hide2`,**`Show2`**,`Hide3`

`Hide1`,**`Show1`**, `Hide2`,**`Show2`**,`Hide3`,**`Show3`**

Comment: You could also just execute the code of `Show` directly in the `Hide` that should call it.

Comment: you are right! idk why i wanted to use asyntask so badly